Examples of semirings where the additive neutral element is not absorbing for multiplication
In the case of a non unital ring, the additive 0 must be absorbing for the multiplication because we have a⋅0 = a⋅(a − a) = a⋅a − a⋅a = 0 and similarly on the other side.
In  the case of a unital semiring we also have a = a⋅1 = a⋅(1 + 0) = a⋅1 + a⋅0 = a + a⋅0,  and similarly on the other side.  Thus, if the additive monoid of our semiring is cancellative we get 0 = a⋅0 from a + 0 = a = a + a⋅0, and similarly on the other side.  So my question is "Is it possible to have examples of a non multiplicatively absorbing additive neutral element in the case of (commutative and not commutative) semirings :

non cancellative, but unital ?
non unital but cancellative ?
non unital and not cancellative ?"


Answer to the third question is affirmative, the free semiring on no generators is an example. It has the following representation. On natural numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, ... let $m\oplus n:=\max(m,n)$ and $m\otimes n:=m+n$. This is a semigroup with respect to $\oplus$, with neutral element $1$, and a (commutative) semiring since $m+\max(n_1,n_2)=\max(m+n_1,m+n_2)$. The $\oplus$-neutral element $1$ does not absorb anything since $1+n\ne n$ for all $n$.

Splendid !Thank you very much.

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე Nice observation, but it's not quite true that $1$ doesn't absorb anything, since it absorbs itself! Thus in the semiring that you describe (which, by the way for those interested, is a key tool in tropical geometry), we have $1+n\ne n$ for all $n\ne1$.

@JoeSilverman But no, $1+1=2\ne1$ too

In the cancellative case, $ab+a0=a(b+0)=ab=ab+0$ implies $a0=0$ and similarly $0a=0$.

In fact, I made an (interesting because I obtained a nice example) error in  my question. The real question is to obtain examples in the three cases of semirings where the additive 0 IS ABSORBING" !

According to my last comment $0$ is absorbing in the cancellative case. For unital non-cancellative examples - the bottom is absorbing in any bounded lattice. And for non-unital non-cancellative example, just take any additive semigroup with zero multiplication, $ab=0$ for all $a$, $b$.

I also made a mistake in the first comment. The $\oplus$-neutral element $1$ does not indeed absorb anything as I claimed, but the reason is $1+n\ne1$ for all $n$, not $1+n\ne n$ (which is also true but irrelevant).

Also, if you modify the example from my first comment by adding $0$, then this $0$ will become neutral element both for $\oplus$ and for $\otimes$ and will absorb itself (as this should be in the unital case), but not anything else.

In fact, I already observed that 0 must be absorbing in the case of a unital and cancellative semiring. Your first example shows a case of a non unital and cancellative (because if m+a=n+a, then m=n) semiring with an additive neutral element (1) that is not absorbing because 1+n > 1 if n > 0).

I agree that taking a bounded distributive lattice, with inf as addition and sup as multiplication, so that inf(x,1) = x and sup(x,1) =1, gives an additive neutral element 1 that is absorbing in a commutative and unital semiring that is not cancellative because x=y  is not garanted if sup(x,z) = sup (y,z).

We get $0=a\cdot0$ from $a+0=a+a\cdot0$ if the additive monoid is cancellative, not multiplicative monoid, n'est-ce pas?

Tout juste !Merci

Doesn't the standard definition of semiring include the axiom $a \cdot 0 = 0 = 0 \cdot a$? See e.g. Wikipedia or Golan's book, where this appears in the definition. So it's a bit unclear what your notion of semiring is. Is it the one where all other axioms are kept while this one is removed? If so. what makes this definition of interest to you?

@TobiasFritz: I think you meant to link to this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring. Your current link is to the page for "stable distribution," which seems unrelated. Anyways I agree with your point that $a \cdot 0 = 0 = 0 \cdot a$ should be an axiom.

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე Probably not worth a protracted discusssion, but your definition is $m\oplus n=\max{m,n}$, so $1\oplus1=1$, not $2$.

@JoeSilverman Yes but does not absorbing means multiplicatively absorbing? $m\otimes n=m+n$, and always $1\otimes n\ne1$
